# Sensitivity Analysis Excel Macro

Tags: vba, excel

The table below is an example sensitivity analysis I'd like to be able to update in a more professional manner (codewise).  I've been able record a macro and modify it a bit was wondering (as I'm sure) if there is a more cleaner way to do this.  Each of the %'s affects a certain part of the spreadsheet that shows the new values.  I take those 2 new values and paste them into a table (one cell block at a time).

So in the example below I set the 2 modifying cells to -10% / -15% and copy the new values (NPV/IRR) into the cell block.  Then proceed to go through the list of %'s and paste the hardcoded values.  So was just wondering if there was a way to loop within a set range (in case the sensitivity %'s change).

```
Range("C52").Value = "-10%"
    Range("C57").Value = "-15%"
        Range("E54:E55").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Range("L48").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

[image: Sensitivity Analysis]

Comment: So are you trying to do a loop such as `For x = -0.1 To 0.1 Step 0.05` and another loop such as `For y = -0.15 To 0.15 Step 0.05`?

Comment: Ah - yes!  that's it.  I will need to do a loop for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using some loops, you will be able to populate your whole table:

```
Sub test()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    'Loop across each column
    For x = 0 To 4
        'Use a value which is 5% higher each time, starting from -10%
        Range("C52").Value = x * 0.05 - 0.1
        'or possibly
        'Range("C52").Value = Cells(47, 12 + x).Value

        'Within each column, loop across each row
        For y = 0 To 6
            'Use a value which is 5% higher each time, starting from -15%
            Range("C57").Value = y * 0.05 - 0.15
            'or possibly
            'Range("C57").Value = Cells(49 + 2 * y, "K").Value

            'Place the calculated values into the appropriate spots in the table
            Cells(48 + 2 * y, 12 + 1 * x).Value = Range("E54").Value
            Cells(49 + 2 * y, 12 + 1 * x).Value = Range("E55").Value

        'Repeat for next row in this column
        Next

    'Repeat for next column
    Next

End Sub
```

Note: I think Excel has a built-in feature to do this sort of thing (populating a table based on calculations performed elsewhere), but I don't think I have ever used it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you mean or what you're trying to do but as a start you could optimise your code somewhat:

```
Range("C52").Value = "-10%"
Range("C57").Value = "-15%"
Range("L48:L49").Value = Range("E54:E55").Value
```

Here I've got rid of selecting, copying and pasting... and just directly said the target range's values is the same as the one you were originally copying.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure whether I explained it that well.  Basically the table I attached would start out blank, and then it needs to be populated by each variation, -10% & -15%, -10% & -10% and so on.  These percentages are linked to other areas in the spreadsheet that manipulate the pricing, volume, etc... (increase sales by 10%, decrease by 10%, etc...).   Then each one of these scenarios recalculates the NPV/IRR.
So the ranges (c52, c57) cycle between all those values to populate the sensitivity table.  Does that help?  Maybe this is too hard to explain.

Comment: Just tackle each part one by one - You could fill the range using absolute references, basically just coding an excel formula that you'd drag to fill... e.g. if your table above has the percentages in row 1 and column A, the table range would be B2:F8. To fill for multiplying the two together, VBA code would be: Range("B2:F8").Formula = ("=$A2*B$1") Try that and see what needs to be done next.